# How Would I Execute an Event at a Specific Time

Tags: java, discord-jda

Currently I am trying to create an timer that notifies me at a specific time every week(1:00PM on Thursday). The problem I am facing right now is that how would I trigger the timer to start without doing any action. I need the timer to start by itself everytime upon bot startup. Any help is appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
public class Reminder extends ListenerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void onGuildMessageReceived(GuildMessageReceivedEvent e) {
        if (e.getGuild().getId().equalsIgnoreCase("77804326694381163")) {
            TextChannel defaultChannel = e.getGuild().getDefaultChannel();
            if (defaultChannel != null) {
                Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
                ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles");
                time.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(zoneId));
                Date timeGet = time.getTime();

                DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EE HH:mm:ss");
                String string = df.format(timeGet);

                if (string.equalsIgnoreCase("Thu 13:00:00")) {
                    Timer timer = new Timer();
                    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            defaultChannel.getChannel().sendTyping().queue();
                            defaultChannel.getChannel().sendMessage("Works").queue();
                        }
                    }, time.getTime(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(7, TimeUnit.DAYS));
                }

            } else if (defaultChannel == null) {
                e.getChannel().sendTyping().queue();
                e.getChannel().sendMessage("Failed to get default channel.").queue();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to think about how you can store a time between different runs. Maybe you could store a DateTime string in a database, or even write it to a file, then when thebot restarts you simply load the data from the database or file, then all your app needs to do is loops every 10s and checks if the times in the list have been reached.

Comment: Hmm, not a bad idea. But is there a simpler way maybe? I thought it'd be a bit easier :p.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by simpler? You need to store the information somewhere between bot restarts, otherwise, you would have to rescan the entire channel contents every time your bot starts to check for previous commands. And while that is possible, it is neither efficient nor effective, and will break when a channel gets too many messages, and discord imposes rate limiters on your bot for trying to scan millions of old messages. Saving to file is relatively easy, there are many tutorials available, but you will want to look into creating a loop, or starting timers with an end/trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use a `ScheduledExecutorService`.

```java
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledActivity = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
scheduledActivity.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
      //whatever you want to do at 11 PM on Thursday
},
initialDelay, //you have to calculate an initial delay
TimeUnit.DAYS.toSeconds(7), //makes it run every 7 days
TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

The `initalDelay` is always the difference between the current time and the time you want your service to run (11 PM on Thursday in your case).

There are several solutions on how to achieve this, but I personally prefer the following approach:

```java
//you might want to change the timezone to your liking
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin"));        
LocalDateTime then = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin"));

//then equals the next or current Thursday on 13:00 (or 1 PM)
then = then.with(TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame(DayOfWeek.THURSDAY)).withHour(13).withMinute(0).withSecond(0);
    
Duration duration = Duration.between(now, then);
long initialDelay = duration.getSeconds();

//initialDelay can become negative if the current day is Thursday but it's already too late
if (initialDelay < 0) {
    //add one week to shift the delay to the next correct time
    initialDelay = Duration.between(now, localDate.with(TemporalAdjusters.next(DayOfWeek.THURSDAY)).withHour(13).withMinute(0).).getSeconds();
}
```

(This definitely can be optimized!)